# Jenkins: Is there a way to have a parent build parameter that enables/disables child build parameters?

Tags: jenkins

I have a paramatized build job that I want to manually trigger.

In this job, the first parameter is a choice (parent) parameter, aka a dropdown list, which has several options to choose from. There are a bunch of other (child) parameters too, but I want them hidden/disabled. However within the (parent parameter) drop down list there is one option, which if selected will enable all the child parameters.

Is it possible to have this kind of setup in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think its possible for now - may be once the switch feature is available in JSON SCHEMA we can use the extended choice plugin to achieve it